# replace one row with 2 rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i replace one row with 5 rows with same data in mysql.for example i have this table

```
 id   |   companyId   |      name       |  open  |  close
 1    |    1          |    mon-fri      |  10:00 |  19:00  
 2    |    1          |      sat        |  10:00 |  12:00 
 3    |    1          |      sun        |  10:00 |  12:00 
 4    |    2          |    mon-fri      |  10:00 |  16:00  
 5    |    2          |      sat        |  10:00 |  13:00 
 6    |    2          |      sun        |  10:00 |  13:00
```

I want to convert name field where its mon-fri to mon , tues , wed , thur , fri .

```
 id   |   companyId   |      name       |  open  |  close
 1    |    1          |    mon     |  10:00 |  19:00  
 2    |    1          |    tues    |  10:00 |  19:00 
 3    |    1          |    wed     |  10:00 |  19:00 
 4    |    1          |    thur    |  10:00 |  19:00   
 5    |    1          |    fri     |  10:00 |  19:00  
 6    |    1          |    sat     |  10:00 |  12:00 
 7    |    1          |    sun     |  10:00 |  12:00 
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this via an `UPDATE`, but what you can do is a series of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` making use of some string literals, followed by a `DELETE` to remove the rows you expanded out.

```
/* First insert a row for each mon,tue,wed,thur,fri */
/* Column values are copied from the existing mon-fri row, and use the literal strings 'mon', 'tue', etc as the new `name` */
INSERT INTO yourtable (`companyId`, `name`, `open`, `close`)
  SELECT `companyId`, 'mon', `open`, `close` FROM yourtable WHERE `name` = 'mon-fri'
INSERT INTO yourtable (`companyId`, `name`, `open`, `close`)
  SELECT `companyId`, 'tue', `open`, `close` FROM yourtable WHERE `name` = 'mon-fri'
INSERT INTO yourtable (`companyId`, `name`, `open`, `close`)
  SELECT `companyId`, 'wed', `open`, `close` FROM yourtable WHERE `name` = 'mon-fri'
INSERT INTO yourtable (`companyId`, `name`, `open`, `close`)
  SELECT `companyId`, 'thur', `open`, `close` FROM yourtable WHERE `name` = 'mon-fri'
INSERT INTO yourtable (`companyId`, `name`, `open`, `close`)
  SELECT `companyId`, 'fri', `open`, `close` FROM yourtable WHERE `name` = 'mon-fri'

/* Then delete the original mon-fri rows which you just expanded out */
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE `name` = 'mon-fri'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cae33/1

*(Credit where due: this excellent suggestion was the work of [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m) in an unsolicited edit)*

You could also reduce the number of statements, as well as the number of table scans, by using a virtual table, like this:

```
/* Cross-join the existing 'mon-fri' rows with a virtual table of day names
   of 'mon' through 'fri' and insert the resulting set back into your table */
INSERT INTO yourtable (`companyId`, `name`, `open`, `close`)
  SELECT t.`companyId`, v.`name`, t.`open`, t.`close`
  FROM yourtable t
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'mon' AS `name` UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tue' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wed' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'thur' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'fri'
  ) v
  WHERE t.`name` = 'mon-fri';

/* Then delete the original mon-fri rows which you just expanded out */
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE `name` = 'mon-fri';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98e35/1

#### Update after comments:

There is no real value to forcing their order when you insert the rows, that is best done in `SELECT`.

To order by day for each `companyId`, it will require some work no matter which way it is done.  You could call `LOWER(STR_TO_DATE())` with `%a` and compare the weekday value, however you would also need to change your `thur` to `thu` since that is how MySQL abbreviates it.  That results in a bunch of function calls.

Instead, you can use a `CASE....` in the `ORDER BY` to assign ordinal values to each day, like:

```
ORDER BY
 companyId,
 CASE `name`
   WHEN 'sun' THEN 1 
   WHEN 'mon' THEN 2
   WHEN 'tue' THEN 3
   WHEN 'wed' THEN 4
   WHEN 'thur' THEN 5
   WHEN 'fri' THEN 6
   WHEN 'sat' THEN 7
 ELSE 8 END
```

#### Neither of the above methods is going to be friendly to indexing though.

If you need this to be more performant, I would recommend against storing the strings `'mon','tue','wed'`,etc in the first place, and instead storing their associated weekday value. See [`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) for details.

Comment: Thnx alot...that's great but how can i order them like mon, tues, wed,thur,fri,sat,sun. for all companies.